# $project inside MongoDB array

Tags: mongodb

I have MongoDB collection `items` with following document:

```
{
    data: [{"name": "First"}, {"name": "Second"}],
    data2: [{"value": 20}, {"value": 30}]
}
```

Is there any way to project `data2.value` into `data.value` on same indexes? I would need this result:

```
{
    data: [
        {"name": "First", value: 20},
        {"name": "Second", value: 30}
    ]
}
```

It would like something like that:

```
db.items.aggregate([{"$project": {"data.X.value": "$data2.X.value", "data2": 0}}]) // Where X "iterate" over all indexes (so 0 and 1).
```

Lengths of arrays `data` and `data2` are always same, but it doesn't have to be 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to loop through object by object of `data` array
- [$indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/index.html) to get the index of current object `$$d`
- [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to get the element `value` of `data2` from particular `$$d` object index

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        $map: {
          input: "$data",
          as: "d",
          in: {
            name: "$$d.name",
            value: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                "$data2.value",
                { $indexOfArray: ["$data", "$$d"] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/wv1vEVsrHeT